# Bolzano-Weierstrass for the sequence ${a_n}=(-1)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've been studying about sequences and I started to read about the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem as stated:

> "Every bounded sequence {a$_n$} has a convergent subsequence"

So I have a question, if I have the sequence: ${a_n}=(-1)^n $, that is, ${a_n}=-1, 1, -1, 1, ...$

It is clearly bounded within the interval: $[-1, 1]$

Since a subsequence is monotone. How can I find a subsequence for it if a term is greater than the previous one, and then the following is lower than the previous one?

Comment: Subsequence is **not** necessarily monotone. Indexes which creates  Subsequence are monotone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for a sub-sequence to be valid, its **indexes** must be increasing - not the values. So, the sequence of indexes $1,3,5$ is valid, but $1,1,3$ or $1,3,2$ aren't.

So, a converging sub-sequence to your original one will be $$1,1,1,1,\ldots \to 1$$
or
$$-1,-1,-1,-1, \ldots \to -1$$

Answer (score 0):

A convergent subsequence of your sequence is $1,1,1,1,...$

Comment: Increasing as well

Comment: not increasing??

Comment: But why if it is not increasing, I mean, 1 < 1 is not true. It must: ${a_n}<{a_{n+1}}$

Comment: It might not be increasing, but it is **monotone increasing** (that is, $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$)